# Snow Leopard and Windows 7 on MacBook White

Tags: snow-leopard, macbook-pro, bootcamp, windows

I have an MacBook White, will it support Snow Leopard and Windows 7 (via BootCamp).

Are there any softwares/apps (in particular) that won't work after I install Snow Leopard and windows7.

**MacBook Specifications**

2.0GHz Intel Core 2 Duo Processor

2GB DDR2 SDRAM

13.3-inch TFT screen

NVIDIA GeForce 9400M graphics processor with 256MB of DDR2 SDRAM shared with Main Memory

NOTE: I know it's old system, but can't help it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are installing windows via bootcamp the two systems will have exclusive use of all resources. You won't have any restrictions on the apps you install other than your existing restrictions of disk space, ram or your graphics processor.

I would suggest upgrading your machine to 4GB of ram as both Snow Leopard and windows 7 like at least 4GB of ram.

Answer (score 1):

Although Microsoft say that 2GB RAM is sufficient for running Windows 7, you'll feel a need to upgrade for the more memory intensive software.  Likewise, many people have successfully ran Snow Leopard with machine specs similar to yours, some even using VMWare/Parrellels (and thus sharing resources, not that I recommend this for low specs).  But I guess the same goes in that you'll feel the struggle when you find you need to run a few 'heavier' applications at once.

Regarding any apps/software that may not work after the upgrade, then your best bet is to check the minimal system requirements for each application that you may use/want to use.  The last thing you want is to upgrade and then find that your machine doesn't meet the required specs for software crucial to your work, studies or even leisure.

Answer (score 1):

A lot of my friends own this MacBook (i'm in a school) and I've helped them install Windows on it. So far, no problems have occurred, and they seem pretty happy about it. 2GB of RAM should be enough for normal uses (my friends play CPU-intensive games, and have no problems too), but if you need to run memory-intensive applications, I recommend that you upgrade your RAM.

There should be no problems with Windows interfering with Mac OS X (separate partitions, and only read access for HFS+ partitions in Windows). However, if you install 64-bit Windows, some applications may not support it. You can still run 32-bit applications though. Remember to follow the Boot Camp Install Guide found [here](http://manuals.info.apple.com/en_US/Boot_Camp_Install-Setup_10.6.pdf), and make a backup in case you do something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Snow Leopard will run just fine on that hardware. As far as windows 7 - you will want to watch closely if you care to have the "Aero" experience.

W7 is more ram hungry than SL - so you might upgrade if you like more speed and more apps open at one time or if Windows 7 feels slow but you certainly meet the minimum specs to install and try it first.

Your windows and associated software will need to support the NVIDIA GeForce 9400M - so just check the product pages to see if your hardware meets their specifications. Nvidia markets that card as 9400G on PC hardware so you might not see 9400M if the vendor doesn't realize it's just the mac installation of the G chip.

Most games and major software will run well or have a page listing in much detail which graphics cards are needed for better frame rates or advanced features such as a CAD or rendering software that is highly optimized.

Answer (score 0):

You should try virtualization as well. There is vmware, parallels both pay solutions and  virtualbox which is free. Virtualization might not be a good option because of your ram limitations. You might have one of the early gen macbooks that could not address over 2-3 gig of ram.